# Python: extract list of data in dict in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

```
n = numpy.array([(0, {'lat': 47.8634123, 'lon': 11.9994587, 'id': 0, 'label': u'271382207'}), 
                 (1, {'lat': 47.8599343, 'lon': 11.9930076, 'id': 1, 'label': u'269321789'}), 
                 (2, {'lat': 47.8601615, 'lon': 11.9933169, 'id': 2, 'label': u'269321788'})])
```

I want to extract all lat,lon tuples as new numpy array. How's that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
numpy.array([(e[1]['lat'], e[1]['lon']) for e in n])
```

This is a basic Python construct that all developers should know about. I suggest you read an introductory book or take a course on Python.

Comment: @user2772305 You should mark this answer as the correct one if it helped you (e.g. by clicking on the check symbol)